# Manter conexão do banco de dados aberta no PHP

Tags: php, session, firebird

Quando utilizamos uma aplicação PHP com banco de dados Firebird utilizamos os métodos `ibase_connect()` para abrir a conexão com o banco de dados e `ibase_close()` para fechar essa conexão. Se a conexão for aberta e não for fechada com a utilização do último comando, ao terminar a execução do comando SQL a conexão é terminada.

E os bancos de dados possuem diferentes performances ao abrir a conexão com o banco de dados, segundo o que me falaram Firebird é um dos bancos de dados em que a conexão demora para abrir, então gostaria de propor uma solução para isso em nossos projetos.

Ela pode ser salva em sessão e é uma maneira que pode ser considerada? Exemplo:

**Database.php**:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    function OpenConnection(){
        if (empty($_SESSION['connection'])){
            $host = 'localhost:/path/to/your.gdb';
            $dbh = ibase_connect($host, $username, $password);
            $_SESSION['connection'] = $dbh;
        }
    }
?>
```

**File1.php**:

```
<?php

    include_once('Database.php');
    OpenConnection();
    $conn = $_SESSION['connection'];

    // Resto das operações

?>
```

**Perguntas**:

1. É considerado uma boa prática a ideia acima?
2. Há outra maneira de fazer? Como?
3. Existe algum(ns) artigo(s) explicando como o Facebook consegue manter uma conexão para cada usuário? Pode mencionar na sua resposta?

Answer (score 5):

Apesar de a pergunta ser sobre Firebird, em geral se aplica a qualquer DB que dependa de conexão.

1. É péssimo, pois se você tiver mil usuários navegando no site, terá mil conexões abertas ao mesmo tempo, quando num uso normal a conexão só ficaria por microsegundos aberta ao se carregar as páginas, e dificilmente as mesmas mil pessoas trocariam de página simultaneamente.
2. A maneira ideal é abrir e fechar a conexão. Se o DB nao te atender bem nestas condições, troque de DB, ou mesmo de linguagem cliente, ou use algum servidor ou interface customizada para o seu caso específico.
3. O [Facebook não usa o mesmo PHP que a maioria das pessoas](http://hacklang.org/), ao contrário do que é divulgado pela metade em alguns lugares (inclusive algumas respostas no próprio SOpt). Eles fizeram uma versão compilável com boa parte da sintaxe do PHP, o que é bem diferente. E o fato de continuarem com a sintaxe do PHP é pelo fato de simplesmente não ter como trocar do dia para a noite a linguagem de programação sem parar tudo, mas eles investem pesado em C++ e [também a linguagem D](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/l37h5s$2gd8$1@digitalmars.com).

Não sei se ainda está em uso, mas mesmo antes da [Hack](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=24413138919), o FB já usava o [HipHop](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2010/02/02/hiphop-for-php--move-fast/), transformando o fonte em PHP em C++, e depois compilando com g++.

Além disso, a infraestrutura de DB de grandes serviços usa sempre bancos que podem ser usados de maneira distribuída. No caso do Facebook, mais especificamente o [Cassandra](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=24413138919). Em vez de você ter um servidor atendendo milhões de pessoas, você tem vários servidores espalhados pelos Datacenters, cada um atendendo uma parte dos usuários.

Sendo o Facebook ou a Quitanda do Mário, o que importa mesmo é saber quais são as necessidades do projeto, e escolher as tecnologias que permitem chegar até o resultado pretendido, e evitar de usar as que não permitem um resultado satisfatório.